# Input field loos focus in Vue when has no results

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, input

I have Vue application. And inside, I have some input field. If this field has any results, the buttons forward and backward are visible, else not.

My problem is, that when I type inside input field, when I type something that has no results, input loose focus. (see snippet)

Hot to solve this?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: "",
    items: [{
        'id': 123,
        'name': 'item1'
      },
      {
        'id': 124,
        'name': 'item2'
      },
      {
        'id': 128,
        'name': 'item3'
      },
      {
        'id': 237,
        'name': 'item4'
      }
    ]
  },

  computed: {

    search_list_of_workorders: function() {
      var self = this;
      var search_string = this.input.toLowerCase();

      // apply filter
      var array = this.search_filter_array(this.items, search_string);

      return array.slice(0, 10).map(a => a.id);
    },

    number_of_search_results: function() {
      return this.search_list_of_workorders.length
    },

    display_results_buttons: function() {
      return this.number_of_search_results > 0
    },
  },

  methods: {
    search_filter_array: function(array, search_string) {

      return array.filter(function(el) {
        var id_filter = el.id.toString().includes(search_string);
        return id_filter;
      });
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <button type="button" v-if="display_results_buttons">
        Back
  </button>
  <div v-if="display_results_buttons">({{ number_of_search_results }})</div>
  <input placeholder="Search" type="text" list="searchDropDown" id="searchInput" name="selectEventInput" v-model="input" />

  <datalist id="searchDropDown">
     <option v-for="(item, index) in search_list_of_workorders" :value="item" :key="`optionEvents_${index}`" >
     </option>
  </datalist>
  <button type="button" v-if="display_results_buttons">
        Forward
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: this happens because you're hiding the other elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-show` instead of `v-if`. This will fix your issue perfectly!

The main difference:

- v-if: Only renders the element to the DOM if the expression passes.
- v-show: Renders all elements to the DOM and then uses the CSS display property to hide elements if the expression fails.

Use cases:

- v-show: expensive initial load, cheap toggling,
- v-if: cheap initial load, expensive toggling.

In your case, toggling is mandatory and it can be required many times, so `v-show` is a better solution. Also, it doesn't require re-rendering and will fix the focus-losing issue as well.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    input: "",
    items: [{
        'id': 123,
        'name': 'item1'
      },
      {
        'id': 124,
        'name': 'item2'
      },
      {
        'id': 128,
        'name': 'item3'
      },
      {
        'id': 237,
        'name': 'item4'
      }
    ]
  },

  computed: {

    search_list_of_workorders: function() {
      var self = this;
      var search_string = this.input.toLowerCase();

      // apply filter
      var array = this.search_filter_array(this.items, search_string);

      return array.slice(0, 10).map(a => a.id);
    },

    number_of_search_results: function() {
      return this.search_list_of_workorders.length
    },

    display_results_buttons: function() {
      return this.number_of_search_results > 0
    },
  },

  methods: {
    search_filter_array: function(array, search_string) {

      return array.filter(function(el) {
        var id_filter = el.id.toString().includes(search_string);
        return id_filter;
      });
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.6/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <button type="button" v-show="display_results_buttons">
        Back
  </button>
  <div v-show="display_results_buttons">({{ number_of_search_results }})</div>
  <input placeholder="Search" type="text" list="searchDropDown" id="searchInput" name="selectEventInput" v-model="input" />

  <datalist id="searchDropDown">
     <option v-for="(item, index) in search_list_of_workorders" :value="item" :key="`optionEvents_${index}`" >
     </option>
  </datalist>
  <button type="button" v-show="display_results_buttons">
        Forward
  </button>
</div>
```